# What are the life cycle methods of a Java Server Page?

Tags: java, jsp, lifecycle

What are the life cycle methods of a Java Server Page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Pre-translated: Before the JSP file has been translated and compiled into the Servlet.
- Translated: The JSP file has been translated and compiled as a Servlet.
- Initialized: Prior to handling the requests in the service method the container calls the jspInit() to initialize the Servlet. Called only once per Servlet instance.
- Servicing: Services the client requests. Container calls this method for each request. 
  Out of service: The Servlet instance is out of service. The container calls the jspDestroy() method.

Comment: Why have you replicated your question text in an answer?